# How to divide dataframe in bins of Night , morning ,afternoon ,evening and count how many rows each session and plot count pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe  to divide data in `night` `morning` `afternoon` and `evening` ,after that i want to count how many rows for night ,morning afternoon and evening and bar plot for count.`now i try this code , its working ok but from 00:01 to 00:59 get empty session column.

```
df=df.assign(session=pd.cut(df.Time.dt.hour,[0,6,12,18,23],labels=['Night','Morning','Afternoon','Evening']))
```

Here is result 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `include_lowest=True` in [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df=df.assign(session=pd.cut(df.Time.dt.hour,
                            [0,6,12,18,23],
                            labels=['Night','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
                            include_lowest=True))
```

And then [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
df['session'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Or:

```
session=pd.cut(df.Time.dt.hour,
               [0,6,12,18,23],
               labels=['Night','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
               include_lowest=True)


session.value_counts().plot.bar()
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=100, freq='30T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': rng})  
#print (df)

session=pd.cut(df.Time.dt.hour,
               [0,6,12,18,23],
               labels=['Night','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
               include_lowest=True)


session.value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Comment: same problem , from 00:01 to 00:59 get empty

Comment: @Nickel or use `[-1,6,12,18,23],` or patameter `right=False` in cut.

Comment: @Nickel - reason is some value lower like `0`, also working `-0.001`